# Two divs with the same height - parent and children

Tags: css, height

I have problem with parent and child `div`. I have to set them to `height: auto;` and `min-height: 100%;`. But the parent div stucks at the height of 100%. How should I set that it will also count the height of its child div?

Thanks!

Code here:

```
  #akce{
  background: url('akce.png') center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  }

      #text-correct{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;

  }
```

Comment: I really don't understand what youre trying to achieve; Can you, please, explain it better (plus add your html)?

Answer (score -1):

I have no trying code up here, but I guess it's because the inner div is an absolute div. Try setting the parent div to `display: table` or put another div after the inner div and set its css to `clear: both`.

Comment: I recommend only posting an answer when you are sure your solution works in OP's scenario, instead of 'I guess'-ing

Comment: Neme, thank you for your answer! Very small nitpick, but convention on Stack Overflow is to leave posts unsigned (I've edited out the signature, hopefully you don't mind).